# Mac OSX app : Issue Related to NSArrayController NSTableView Core data Adding Record

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have using `NSArrayController` `NSTableView` and `Core data` **binding**.

I have take one `button` and connect `add:` method of `NSArrayController` to its action.

On Adding new record

`TableView` added and shows new record.
`NSArrayController's` `add`: method called

Problem :
Value is not added into core data (Sqlite type).

On application relaunching shows old data.

Comment: Are you saving/synchronising coredata context?

Comment: I am not saving context, on add: action data is added into arraycontroller and show in tableview. in case of arraycontroller and nstableview binding is i need to add extra code for saving context

Comment: And where to add context save code

Comment: Could be anything. What did you bind to what? When/how do you set `managedObjectContext` of the array controller? What are the settings of the array controller in the Attributes inspector in IB? Is this a Document-Based app?

Answer (score 0):

This is an apple example code. Basically it tries to save the context before app is terminated. Depending on your specific case you might move the functionality to somewhere else.

```
func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
    // Save changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

    if !context.commitEditing() {
        NSLog("\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))) unable to commit editing to terminate")
        return .terminateCancel
    }

    if !context.hasChanges {
        return .terminateNow
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError

        // Customize this code block to include application-specific recovery steps.
        let result = sender.presentError(nserror)
        if (result) {
            return .terminateCancel
        }

        let question = NSLocalizedString("Could not save changes while quitting. Quit anyway?", comment: "Quit without saves error question message")
        let info = NSLocalizedString("Quitting now will lose any changes you have made since the last successful save", comment: "Quit without saves error question info");
        let quitButton = NSLocalizedString("Quit anyway", comment: "Quit anyway button title")
        let cancelButton = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button title")
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = question
        alert.informativeText = info
        alert.addButton(withTitle: quitButton)
        alert.addButton(withTitle: cancelButton)

        let answer = alert.runModal()
        if answer == .alertSecondButtonReturn {
            return .terminateCancel
        }
    }
    // If we got here, it is time to quit.
    return .terminateNow
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your binding code maybe? It is hard to tell what is wrong with so many assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing setting the [managedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsobjectcontroller/1530382-managedobjectcontext) and [entityName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsobjectcontroller/1535467-entityname) on NSArrayController.